# tab computation is not working after installation of c shell in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

after installing c shell all arrow and tab computation is not working. ^[[A ^[[B is printed instead of arrow. kindly help 
thank you

Comment: Does the C Shell even support all that?

Comment: Is the `tcsh` an option?

Answer (score 1):

The space, tab, and new-line-character are used by the C shell to indicate the end of one argument, and the beginning of the next.

It does not have "tab completion" nor does it accept arrow keys.

If you want those use another shell. bash, tcsh, zsh for instance all support tab completion. I would use tcsh:

[tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh)  is a Unix shell based on and compatible with the C shell (csh). It is essentially the C shell with programmable command-line completion, command-line editing, and a few other features.